# iOS 10 Crash when using font

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10

I'm trying to upgrade my app to iOS10 but it crashs at the beginning and Xcode stops on the file where I have all my font. For example :

```
static var RegisterBackToLoginFont:UIFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 16)!;
```

And I read in the release notes that :

> Referencing a system font by name in a call to +[UIFont
>   fontWithName:size:] causes a crash. For more information, see
>   https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/804/

Do you know the new syntax ? Because I've seen this :

```
let myOtherFont = UIFont.fontWithDescriptor(systemFont.fontDescriptor()
                                            size:mySize)
```

But I don't know how to use fontDescriptor.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

```
let fontDescriptor = CTFontDescriptorCreateWithNameAndSize("HelveticaNeue-Light" as CFString, 20.0)
```

will create you a new CTFontDescriptor

Sorry, I missed the point it was a system font.
Did you try the following?

```
let fontDescriptor = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0).fontDescriptor
let newFont        = UIFont(descriptor: fontDescriptor, size: 20.0)
```

Comment: But how can I use CTFontDescriptor with/or to create UIFont ?  "Instance member 'font' cannot be used on type 'Fonts'" is the error message i've got

Comment: I edited my reply above to add in some more information - is that what you're looking for?